# I'm a beginner in NODE.JS Development and i'm accessing an API and i want the value to be displayed in the web browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I'm currently a web application and i'm having a hard time in figuring out how to display the output in the web browser instead of displaying it in the terminal

```
    `var optionsget = {
  host : 'localhost',
  port : 8888,
  path : '/getname.php/name?primary_name=lance'
}


console.log('Options prepared: ');
console.log(optionsget);
console.log('do the get call');


var reqGet = http.request(optionsget, function(res){
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  res.on('data', function(d){
    console.info('Get result: \n');
    process.stdout.write(d);
    console.info('\n\nCall completed');

  });
});

reqGet.end();
reqGet.on('error', function(e){
  console.error(e);
});

var optionsgetmsg = {
  host : 'localhost',
  port : 8888,
  path : '/get.php/name?primary_name=lance',
  method : 'GET'
};
console.log('Options prepared: ');
console.log(optionsgetmsg);
console.log('do the get call');

var reqGet = https.request(optionsgetmsg, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);

    res.on('data', function(d) {
        console.info('GET result after POST:\n');
        process.stdout.write(d);
        console.info('\n\nCall completed');
    });

});

reqGet.end();
reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Here is my code, i'm accessing an api that produce a json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  fallowing code .

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

1. open notepad
2. copy and paste above code inside the file.
3. save it with .js extension as app.js
4. execute command node app.js
5. open browser and type http://127.0.0.0:3000

YOU CAN SEE YOUR HELLO WORD ON WEB BROWSER

Comment: it works, what about sending the data into the browser? the one that i console log, as you can see in the code above.

Comment: res.end('Hello World\n');
this line sending data to browser .

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a web framework like ExpressJS / Hapi or Koa.

This [example](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) below from ExpressJS will output `Hello World!` when you navigate to `localhost:3000/` in browser.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see what you are currently using in your node backend and how your sending data to the terminal output, but here is an example of a route that will send data back to the web browser using the res/response object of express.

This snippet assumes use of express, and a working database connection if that's how you are retrieving data.

If you can post your current code and details of what you're retrieving, providing an actual code sample would be easier

```
app.get('/yourPath', function(req,res){
   //this sends your message to the console
   console.log("Getting data");

   //query to retrieve all documents in collection
   query = {};

   //finds all documents in "yourcollection", passes in query, 
   //callback handles error messages and result (r)  
   db.collection("yourcollection").find(query,
    function(err,r){
      if (err) throw err;

      //preview result (r) in console
      console.log(r);

      //send result (r) to front end  or API using response object
      res.send(r);
    });
});
```

Comment: i already edit my post. i put there the codes. I'm not using database right now .